# Organizing Files in Excel using VBA and FileSystemObject

Tags: excel, vba, filesystemobject

I tried to get this to sort in ascending order from the time and it is not quite working right. It adds all the information, but does not sort the value.  Also, I need to add a cut-off so it only uploads the files within the last week (7 days) from the current date. I'm not sure of an effective way to do this.

Thanks!

```
Option Explicit
Sub ListFiles()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("Sheet2").Select 
With Range("A1")
    .Formula = "Folder contents:"
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Font.Size = 12
End With
Range("A3").Formula = "Folder Path:"
Range("B3").Formula = "File Name:"
Range("C3").Formula = "Creation Date:"

ListFolders "C:\Users\blake.rupprecht\Desktop\Photos\"

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Sub ListFolders(SourceFolderName As String)

Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim SourceFolder As Scripting.Folder
Dim r As Long
Dim sfil As String
Dim par As String

Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Set SourceFolder = FSO.GetFolder(SourceFolderName)

On Error Resume Next
sfil = Dir(SourceFolderName & "\" & "*.jpg*")
Do Until sfil = ""
    Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
    ActiveCell.Hyperlinks.Add ActiveCell, SourceFolderName & "\" & sfil, , , sfil
    ActiveCell.Offset(, 1).Value = SourceFolder.Files(sfil).DateCreated
    ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
    sfil = Dir$
Loop

Columns("A:B").AutoFit

Set SourceFolder = Nothing
Set FSO = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking for 7 days tmie span:

```
If Now - SourceFolder.Files(sfil).DateCreated < 7 Then
    Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
    ActiveCell.Hyperlinks.Add ActiveCell, SourceFolderName & "\" & sfil, , , sfil
    ActiveCell.Offset(, 1).Value = SourceFolder.Files(sfil).DateCreated
    ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
End If
```

Please note that the calculation takes time of day into consideration also. If you want just the date, you have to extract integers from operands.

To sort the values, record some sorting and then remodule that code to fit your scenario.

Comment: I usually use your method.  Just wanted to add that if you wanted to compare dates without including time of day, you should be able to do so using the `Format()` function.  i.e. `If Format(Now(),"mm/dd/yyyy") - Format(SourceFolder.Files(sFil).Date), "mm/dd/yyyy"<7` or something like that  -just off the top of my head, may need to adjust syntax.  You could probably use the `Date()` function in place of `Format(Now())` but I believe this is dependant on environment so could give you funny results on another machine where the system date format is different.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort in ascending order, the easiest thing would probably be to add the results to an array, then use a comparison to re-order the array in ascending order, and then write the values to the cells from the array.  I'll post an example when I get back to the office.

Code is untested, but should work.  Let me know if it doesn't and I'll setup a workbook to test it in.  Also, you could break the sorting code out into it's own function, then it's reusable in other routines.  Do as you see fit.

I removed the `On Error Resume Next` statement because it wasn't necessary where you had it.  Turning off error notifications is only going to mask errors and make it harder to troubleshoot problems with your code.  If you expect errors, write something to handle them, don't just ignore them.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ListFiles()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    With Range("A1")
        .Formula = "Folder contents:"
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Font.Size = 12
    End With
    Range("A3").Formula = "Folder Path:"
    Range("B3").Formula = "File Name:"
    Range("C3").Formula = "Creation Date:"

    ListFolders "C:\Users\blake.rupprecht\Desktop\Photos\"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Sub ListFolders(SourceFolderName As String)

    Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim SourceFolder As Scripting.Folder
    Dim r As Long
    Dim sfil As String
    Dim par As String
    Dim lngX As Long
    Dim lngY As Long
    Dim strX As String
    Dim strY As String
    Dim strTemp As String
    Dim strFiles() As String

    ReDim strFiles(0)
    Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set SourceFolder = FSO.GetFolder(SourceFolderName)

    sfil = Dir(SourceFolderName & "\*.jpg*")
        Do Until LenB(sfil) = 0
            If Now - SourceFolder.files(sfil).DateCreated < 7 Then
                    If lngX = 0 And LenB(strFiles(lngX)) = 0 Then
                        strFiles(0) = sfil
                    Else
                        ReDim Preserve strFiles(UBound(strFiles) + 1)
                        strFiles(UBound(strFiles)) = sfil
                    End If
            End If
        Loop


    'Sort the array in ascending order
    If LenB(srfiles(LBound(strFiles))) > 0 Then
            For lngY = 0 To UBound(strFiles) - 1
                    For lngX = 0 To UBound(strFiles) - 1
                    'Grab the current and next item in the list to compare
                        strX = strFiles(lngX)
                        strY = strFiles(lngX + 1)
                        'Check if the current item is greater than the next in the list and swap them if it is
                            If strX > strY Then
                                strTemp = strFiles(lngX)
                                strFiles(lngX) = strFiles(lngX + 1)
                                strFiles(lngX + 1) = strTemp
                            End If
                    'Reset the temporary strings so we don't accidentally use the wrong value in case of some unforeseen error
                        strTemp = vbNullString
                        strX = vbNullString
                        strY = vbNullString
                    Next lngX
            Next lngY
    End If


    For lngX = LBound(strFiles) To UBound(stfiles)
            With Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).offset(1)
                .Hyperlinks.Add ActiveCell, SourceFolderName & "\" & strFiles(lngX), , , strFiles(lngX)
                .offset(, 1).Value = SourceFolder.files(strFiles(lngX)).DateCreated
            End With
    Next

    Columns("A:B").AutoFit

    Set SourceFolder = Nothing
    Set FSO = Nothing

End Sub
```